# Using functions to populate Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I get the following output from the code:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
gdu = {}
gdu = {
      "b" => 4,
      "c" => arr,
      "d" => arr.map {|x| x * gdu["b"].to_i },
      "e" => gdu["b"].to_i
}
gdu.default = "value does not exit in hash gdu"
gdu # => {"b"=>4, "c"=>[1, 2, 3], "d"=>[0, 0, 0], "e"=>0}
```

Why does the code here have this output?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are surprised by or don't understand?

Comment: Well I expected gdu["d"] to output [4,8,12] and "e" to be 4

Comment: Ok, see my answer below then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the whole hash’s value at once, as one atomic operation. RHO uses the *current* version of `gdu`, which is an empty hash at the moment.

To achieve what you wanted, assign values step by step:

```
gdu = {}
gdu["b"] = 4
gdu["c"] = arr
gdu["d"] = arr.map { |x| x * gdu["b"] } # `to_i` is redundant
gdu["e"] => gdu["b"]
```

Comment: I see that now. I thought that I could simultaneously set the value of "e" to "b" as I defined the Hash, but what happens is that the declaration accesses the empty hash that already exists in memory.

Answer (score 3):

- As for `"b" => 4`, it should be trivial.
- As for `"c" => [1, 2, 3]`, it follows from `arr = [1,2,3]`.
- As for `"d" => [0, 0, 0]`, it goes like this:

  ```
  gdu               # => {}
  gdu["b"]          # => nil
  gdu["b"].to_i     # => 0
  x * gdu["b"].to_i # => 0
  arr.map {|x| x * gdu["b"].to_i } # => [1, 2, 3].map {|x| 0} # => [0, 0, 0]
  ```
- As for `"e" => 0`, it is obvious from the step above.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the code here has this output?

Because Ruby first evaluates the right-hand side of the assignment and then assigns the result (a new hash) to `gdu`.

It becomes obvious if you separate the hash creation and the assignment:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
gdu = {}

hash = {
      "b" => 4,
      "c" => arr,
      "d" => arr.map {|x| x * gdu["b"].to_i },
      "e" => gdu["b"].to_i
}
#=> {"b"=>4, "c"=>[1, 2, 3], "d"=>[0, 0, 0], "e"=>0}

gdu = hash
#=> {"b"=>4, "c"=>[1, 2, 3], "d"=>[0, 0, 0], "e"=>0}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking why the "d" and "e" values have zeros?

Try running just:

```
gdu = {}
puts gdu["b"].to_i
```

you will see that you get zero here too. So you are getting zeros because "b" has not been set to anything yet, as all of the values are set at the same time.